# React Native iOS stuck on LaunchScreen

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, launch-screen

I test my app on the iOS simulator without a problem, on Android everything is fine, but when I download the app on the iPhone, it doesn't work. It gets stuck in the LaunchScreen and suddenly closes after about 10 seconds.

I have no clue why. I already tried a possible solution that was to specify the node version on the Build Phases > Bundle React Native code and images

App on Android already released but I'm facing this issue on iOS.

Comment: Just change to release and see if it works. Probably your WiFi or something not right as it has to be connected to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Debug
2. Same Wifi
3. No VPN on
4. Plug in your device via USB

Comment: It was the wifi. It happens that the iPhone I was testing had the three know wifi networks. Thanks1